# AttributeError: type object 'p' has no attribute 'speed'

Tags: python, class, sorting, key

Why I get AttributeError: type object 'p' has no attribute 'speed'. I clearly defined speed in example you can see below. Why this happens. Here is what I have in the code:

```
class p(object):
    def __init__(self, name, speed):
        self.name = name
        self.speed = speed

ch1 = p('n1', 1)
ch2 = p('n2', 2)
ch3 = p('n3', 3)

e1 = p('e1', 1)
e2 = p('e2', 2)
e3 = p('e3', 3)


class party():
    def __init__(self, group=[]):
        self.group = group

pg = party
pg.group = [ch1, ch2, ch3]

eg = party
eg.group = [e1, e2, e3]


def turn_order(ag, dg):
    uic = []

    for unit in ag.group:
        uic.append(unit)

    for unit in dg.group:
        uic.append(unit)

    order = sorted(uic, key=p.speed)


    return order

order = turn_order(pg, eg)

print order
```

Comment: It looks like p itself is not defined inside your function turn_order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sort a list of *instances* of the *class* `p` by their speed.

The error message `AttributeError: type object 'p' has no attribute 'speed'` is telling you that the *class* p has no speed attribute.

This is true: *instances* of p have a speed attribute, but the *class* p does not.

Also, the `key` argument to `sorted`, [must be a function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), not a simple attribute:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default
>   value is None (compare the elements directly).

To sort by an attribute of the instances in your list, you can do:

`order = sorted(uic, key=lambda x: x.speed)`

`lambda x: x.speed` is an anonymous function that accepts an object as an argument and returns its `speed` attribute.  This is the same as:

```
def get_speed(obj):
    return obj.speed

order = sorted(uic, key=get_speed)
```

Alternatively, you could add a method to `p` that you could use for sorting:

```
class p(object):
    def __init__(self, name, speed):
        self.name = name
        self.speed = speed

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed

order = sorted(uic, key=p.get_speed)
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined p object in `turn_order` function.

In order to use p, you need to create instance of the class and only then to call the instance method.

When you call `p.speed`, it tries to find a static member called speed which you don't have.

Example for solution:

```
def turn_order(ag, dg):
    uic = []

    for unit in ag.group:
        uic.append(unit)

    for unit in dg.group:
        uic.append(unit)
    order = sorted(uic, key=lambda u : u.speed)
```

Comment: I get TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Thanks for answers